# Как сделать подгрузку сразу всей страницы, а не по частям?

Tags: html, javascript

Т.е. подождать пока страница полностью загрузится, и потом показать её.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435015/how-can-i-make-the-browser-wait-to-display-the-page-until-its-fully-loaded

Comment: Что будет видеть пользователь пока грузится страница? Белый экран, огромную бессмысленную полосу прокрутки в центре, предыдущую страницу с маленькой полосой в углу? Прошу прощения за ответ вопросом на вопрос.

Comment: Огромную бессмысленную полосу прогресса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для div`а с сайтом поставить style="display:none", т.е.:

```
<div id=main style="display:none;">
<!--САЙТ-->
</div>
```

А потом в head пропишите:

```
<script>
window.onload=function(){
document.getElementById('main').style.display='block';
}
</script>
```

Должно рабоать, как Вы хотите.

Comment: А если для <body> поставить значение? Мне кажется так будет получше

Comment: Для body не знаю, мне кажется, что что-то ни так будет)))